# Windows 10 shows inconsistent folder sizes - what is the cause?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've just bought a laptop that has Windows 10 pre-installed and would like to dual-boot linux. To this end I'm trying to check how much disk space Windows itself is using so I can decide how large a partition to allocate. I'm finding it ridiculously hard to get a definitive answer to something so simple. I haven't used Windows for a while so perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.

If I right-click on the C: drive in File Explorer, and select Properties, it gives me a disk usage: roughly 41GB.

However if I download sysinternals' du utility and run it on the C: drive, it reports 23,134,749,584 bytes on disk - that's about 21.5GB. Why is File Explorer reporting nearly double this number? So far as I can tell, du is showing hidden folders in its summary. Is there something else it is missing?

What's more, if I go back to File Explorer and right-click each individual folder in the C: drive and look at their individual Properties, their sizes add up to something consistent with the du report (i.e. close to 21GB, not 41GB).

So I can't make File Explorer's reported disk usage on the C: drive agree with anything else I can see. At the same time it's the larger number and I don't want to dismiss it in case the other tools are missing some "real" usage.

Can anyone help me explain the discrepancy?

Comment: Maybe you have some shadow copies, for example via System Restore.

Comment: I can't find a duplicate right now, but this question was asked here at least a few times. The short answer is Properties are always right.

Comment: You might try a third-party GUI tool such as TreeSize Free to find just where all the files are https://jam-software.com/treesize_free/

Comment: Thanks for the help! It does look like the larger Properties number is right, and TreeSize Free is really useful. It looks like the answer is that du can't see a lot of files, even when run as administrator - not sure exactly which types of files it can't see, or if there is a fix for this.